# Time complexity worst case and best case for Djikstra's algo?

Tags: python, time-complexity, dijkstra

Could someone explain the time complexity (worst case and vest case) of the below Djikstra algorithm line by line? I could not find a detailed explanation anywhere, so any help would be appreciated.

```
def dijkstra(graph,start,pharmacy):           
    minimumContainmentZones = {}
    predecessor = {}
    unseenNodes = deepcopy(graph)             
    infinity = 9999999
    path = []
    for node in unseenNodes:
        minimumContainmentZones[node] = infinity
    minimumContainmentZones[start] = 0
 
    while unseenNodes:
        minNode = None
        for node in unseenNodes:
            if minNode is None:
                minNode = node
            elif minimumContainmentZones[node] < minimumContainmentZones[minNode]:
                minNode = node
 
        for childNode, weight in graph[minNode].items():
            if weight + minimumContainmentZones[minNode] < minimumContainmentZones[childNode]:
                minimumContainmentZones[childNode] = weight + minimumContainmentZones[minNode]
                predecessor[childNode] = minNode
        unseenNodes.pop(minNode)
 
    currentNode = pharmacy
    while currentNode != start:
        try:
            path.insert(0,currentNode)
            currentNode = predecessor[currentNode]
        except:
            print('Path not reachable')
            break
    path.insert(0,start)
    if minimumContainmentZones[pharmacy] != infinity:
        return(pharmacy,minimumContainmentZones[pharmacy],str(path))
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be more suitable if you desire a breakdown of your code although, it's asking a bit much to have someone go through it "line by line" though

Comment: Let `n` denote the number of nodes in your graph. Then `while unseenNodes` takes O(n) in any case (you have to proceed every node once). Inside that loop you have `for node in unseedNodes`. This scans through all remaining nodes. So it scans through `n` nodes in the first, through `n-1` in the second, etc. This is again O(n). Any node can not have more than n-1 neighbors, so the `for childNode` loop has between 0 and n-1 iterations, again O(n). Here the best and worst case may differ, which does not matter as it is in any case dominated by the min.finding loop. Thus complexity is O(n*n).

Comment: Note that the performance may become more interesting if you use a priority queue instead of finding the minimum distance node from scratch in every iteration. You may want to check out the Wikipedia page for Dijkstra's algorithm, it explains the algorithm and its variant in details. You can match your code with that explanation.